# Use a GWT app as a module on another GWT app?

Tags: gwt

How do I use a GWT application as a module on another GWT application? The first application has screens on it which I want to integrate into the other GWT application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already explained in *Google Web Toolkit Dev Guide*. Please have a look at below link:

- [Modules: Units of configuration](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules)

---

### How to do it?

To inherit a module, edit your project's module XML file and specify the logical name of the module you want to inherit in the `<inherits>` tag.

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.junit.JUnit"/>
```

**Note:** Modules are always referred to by their logical names. The logical name of a module is of the form `pkg1.pkg2.ModuleName` (although any number of packages may be present). The logical name includes neither the actual file system path nor the file extension.

Comment: Thanks. I was getting some errors and liked to confirm if the task is really possible. As it turns out, it is possible. I just have to be careful in trying to select which classes to convert to javascript.